# Django set autofield value in bulk_create

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to bulk_create a lot of records in a new table in my PostgresQL db.

The primary key on the table is an AutoField called `id`.

As of Django 1.10 (which I'm using), this should work in Postgres: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

However, the bulk_create is failing with the following error.
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`

Which suggests that the `id` field isn't automatically assigned a value.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you show us your model and the `bulk_create` call, just in case?

Comment: Sure!
Model is here: https://github.com/uclapi/uclapi/compare/checkout-db#diff-c951c90934ea52618376c7d5e183c200R34
Bulk create is here: https://github.com/uclapi/uclapi/compare/checkout-db#diff-b2581b0a9c01e3f99aec2e29094adbe9R65

Disregard the why we're doing this, lack of tests, etc. :P

Comment: The other option we've been considering is using uuids as primary keys and just generating them as part of the `bulk_create`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is not really an answer, but it's what worked for us:

We replaced the explicit `id` AutoField with an implicit one (ie. removed the line, and let Django generate it itself).

And then it worked!